# Returning Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Tags: r, standards, population, deviation

I'm struggling to get the following code working.
The data I have is a data.frame of a physical test. Athletes who did the test are classified based on a 'Sport Specific' paramater.

```
wingate_benchmarks <- wingate_data %>%
        select(`Sport Specific`,`Minimum power output`,`Average power output`,
           `Relative Average Power`,`Peak Power`,`Time to peak`,`Max. RPM`,`Time to Max. RPM`,`Total Work`) %>%
        group_by(`Sport Specific`) %>%
        dplyr::summarize_at(vars(`Minimum power output`,`Average power output`,
                      `Relative Average Power`,`Peak Power`,`Time to peak`,`Max. RPM`,`Time to Max. RPM`,`Total Work`),
                 list(mean = mean, sd = sqrt((n()-1)/n())*sd))
```

If I use only sd, it calculates the Standard Deviation as if the data is a sample, but it should be considered as the full popluation. Hence the `sqrt((n()-1)/n())` addition.

But R keeps returning: **Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.**

Is there anyway to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing more than just providing the name of the function, you need to provide a "purr-style lambda".  Something like `se = ~sd(.)*sqrt((n()-1)/n()))`.  Also, `summarise_at` has been superseded by `across()`.  Note how to reference the base function `sd` in the lambda.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt, not certain if it will work with your data.

```r
wingate_data %>%
  select(`Sport Specific`, `Minimum power output`, `Average power output`,
         `Relative Average Power`, `Peak Power`, `Time to peak`,
         `Max. RPM`, `Time to Max. RPM`, `Total Work`) %>%
  group_by(`Sport Specific`) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    across(`Minimum power output`, `Average power output`, `Relative Average Power`,
           `Peak Power`, `Time to peak`, `Max. RPM`, `Time to Max. RPM`, `Total Work`,
           list(mean = ~ mean(.), sd = ~ sqrt((n()-1)/n()) * sd(.))
           ))
```

We can see it in action using `mtcars`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(
    across(vs:carb,
           list(mean = ~ mean(.), sd = ~ sqrt((n()-1)/n()) * sd(.))
           ))
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#     cyl vs_mean vs_sd am_mean am_sd gear_mean gear_sd carb_mean carb_sd
#   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     4   0.909 0.287   0.727 0.445      4.09   0.514      1.55   0.498
# 2     6   0.571 0.495   0.429 0.495      3.86   0.639      3.43   1.68 
# 3     8   0     0       0.143 0.350      3.29   0.700      3.5    1.5
```

As @Limey said in their comment, the [`summarize_*`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) functions have been superseded by `across`, which generally takes two arguments: the variables (in `tidyselect` fashion), and some form of function(s).

The functions can be provided in several ways:

- literal functions, `summarize(across(vs:carb, mean))`;
- anon-funcs, `summarize(across(vs:carb, function(z) mean(z)/2))`;
- `rlang`-style tilde funcs, `summarize(across(vs:carb, ~ mean(.)))`, where the `.` is replaced with the column (vector); or
- a named-list with any of the above, such as we demonstrated in the `mtcars` working answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I have it working now :-)